# Error in Beanshell Sampler JMeter for parsing RegularExpressionExtractor

Tags: java, regex, jmeter, beanshell

Setting below sample result in jar file

```
mySampleResult.setResponseData("ReturnCode" + returnCode + "EndReturnCode" ,null);
```

copy the jar file in `lib/ext` of `JMeter`.

Create a project where `Regular expression extractor` is attached to java request which calls runtest in jar file

Response string is below

```
ReturnCodeThu Feb 16 08:01:56 GMT 2017,Thu Feb 16 09:09:27 GMT 2017,0:1:7:31,98.74105EndReturnCode
```

Regular Expression Extractor

```
Reference Name: returnValue
Regular Expression: ReturnCode(.*?)EndReturnCode
```

Beanshell Code

```
 ${returnValue}
```

Error in Beanshell

```
Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  In file: inline evaluation of: ``  try {     Thu Feb 16 08:01:56 GMT 2017,Thu Feb 16 09:09:27 GMT 2017,0:1:7:31,9 . . . '' Encountered "16" at line 4, column 13.
```

Please let me know that why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `${returnValue}`statement is syntaxically incorrect, you need at least to surround it with quotation marks like `"${returnValue}"` so Beanshell interpreter would treat it as a [Java String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Going forward, just putting this statement inside the Beanshell Sampler doesn't make any sense, you should add some further processing, i.e:

- `return "${returnValue}";` - will set Beanshell Sampler result to this value
- `SampleResult.setResponseData("${returnValue}".getBytes());` - the same as above but using [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) shorthand
- `print("${returnValue}");` - output the value to [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29)
- `log.info("${returnValue}");` - output the value to *jmeter.log* file

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for more information on using Beanshell in JMeter scripts

Comment: I normally ignore this form of comments, but you seem to be not only ignorant, but a little bit arrogant as well. 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTvVf.png

Comment: Sorry, my bad. But the feature seems to be undocumented!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just print the value to JMeter log file, use `log.info` method and using `vars.get`.

BeanShell Code:

```
log.info("returnValue " + vars.get("returnValue"));
```

Answer (score -2):

Way access to JMeter variable from Beanshell is different from what you've been supposed.

You're going to use "vars" built-in Beanshell object (or variable, if you like).

```
whatsActuallyReturned = vars.get("returnValue");
vars.put("returnValue", "whatever I want to put instead");
```