# Jmeter: validating Code in Beanshell Sampler

Tags: variables, printing, jmeter, getvalue

Here is the simple code

```
 vars.put("str" , "${__time(dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS)}");
 log.info("${str}");
```

I am expecting to see the value of `str` in logs but I am getting `${str}`. I am validating it because I have to assign the current time to a variable and later want to use it in script. But I am not getting the value stored in `str`.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275610/error-in-beanshell-sampler-jmeter-for-parsing-regularexpressionextractor

Answer (score 1):

try as follows using `vars.get`:

```
vars.put("str" , "${__time(dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS)}");
log.info("str " + vars.get("str"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend inlining functions and/or variables into Beanshell script as you may face syntax error issues, i.e. type mismatch if the value has quotation marks.

So either use `log.info(vars.get("str"));` or use [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination to see JMeter variables values.

[image: Variables set by Beanshell]

More information: [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)